# Node exec exit to mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, exec

Trying to make a simple utility script in node to start a remote mongo shell.  Is there a way to run this in node and exit to the resulting shell?  The script below starts the mongo shell for a second, then exits and hangs.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var env_vars = require('./env_vars')('dev');
if(env_vars){
    for (var key in env_vars){
        process.env[key] = env_vars[key];
    }
}

var mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_URL.replace('mongodb://', '');
var parse_url = mongo_url.split('@');
var parse_un_ps = parse_url[0].split(':');

var shell_login =
    'mongo ' +
    parse_url[1] +
    ' -u ' +
    parse_un_ps[0] +
    ' -p ' +
    parse_un_ps[1];

//console.log(shell_login);
exec(shell_login);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think using the child_process.spawn with stdio inheritance will result in the behavior you're looking for.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var node = spawn('mongo', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Pass in an array of arguments as the second argument to spawn().

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: Please provide a full example that does what op is looking for. Your code omits the authentication arguments that op had in his `shell_login` variable